# D3.js graph in google maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, d3.js

I am trying to get the D3 graph in a Info Window for google maps

I am trying to achieve this by adding this simple D3 graph(http://jsfiddle.net/fiatjaf/aK6DP/) code in a google maps infowindow(https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) example

part of code where I append the graph to MAP(info window)

```
var svg = d3.select("#D3")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

*this code is to ful fill the requirements to post the question do not mark me down please*

**I have all the code in this below fiddle**

Here is what I have come up with https://jsfiddle.net/sgeoayzc/1/ but for some reason the map does not come up on the infowindow HTML div TAG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the dynamic nature of Info Window SVG element that represents a graph should be added differently, for example:

1)create a *detached* element for a graph:

```
var container = d3.select(document.createElement("div"));
```

2)insert graph into Info Window:

```
var graphHtml = container.node().outerHTML; 
infowindow.setContent(graphHtml);
```

In addition there are some issues related with changes in `D3 V4`,for example time format function `d3.time.format` has been replaced by `d3.timeFormat`

Follow [D3 4.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) for a more details.

**Updated** [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/bmb4mLd0/2/)